# How to access date fields of ActivityHistories and OpenActivities

Tags: trigger, date, field-update, activities

I have a SOQL query to retrieve the date values but I am unable to set the fields. Where am I going wrong? This trigger is still in progress.

```
trigger AccountActivityDateRollUp on Account (before insert, before update)
{
    Account ActivityHistories = [SELECT Id,(SELECT ActivityDate FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC LIMIT 1),
                  (SELECT ActivityDate FROM OpenActivities ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account];
    Account OpenActivities = [SELECT Id, (SELECT ActivityDate FROM OpenActivities ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account];

    for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
    {
        acc.Next_Contact_Date__c = ActivityHistories.get(ActivityDate);
        acc.Last_Contact_Date__c = OpenActivities.get(ActivityDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The return type of the inner query will be in form of a list therefore you cannot get date directly from the Object.

> ActivityHistories.get(ActivityDate);  //Probably will not work

2. The ActivityDate is only available in two cases ([From SFDC Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm))

> Indicates one of the following:
>
> > 1. The due date of a task
> > 2. The due date of an event if IsAllDayEvent is set to true
>
> This field has a time stamp that is always set to midnight in the
>   Universal Time Coordinated (UTC) time zone. The time stamp doesn’t
>   represent the time of the activity; don’t attempt to alter it to
>   accommodate time zone differences. Label is Date.

3. Since you are sorting the records in ASC order without NULL criteria. It is likely that you will receive a blank date if the due date is not set.
4. There can be several activities under an Account. Which one would you like to Map.

However I tried the code and I belive this will work:

```
trigger AccountActivityDateRollUp on Account (before insert, before Update)
{
    Account accData = [SELECT Id,(SELECT ActivityDate FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC LIMIT 1),
                  (SELECT ActivityDate FROM OpenActivities ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account Limit 1];

    for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
    {
        acc.Next_Contact_Date__c=accData.ActivityHistories.get(0).ActivityDate;
    }
}
```

As you said that the trigger is still in progress, I suggest to bulkify your code and add a limit on the query.

Comment: I am being given a list index out of bounds exception when I try to save an account?  "execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 Trigger.AccountActivityDateRollUp: line 9, column 1"

Comment: If you are using the code that is in the answer, that essentially means that there are no activities for that account, You can check if accData.ActivityHistories.size()>0 before assigning.

Comment: I still get the error. Is it because there is no list declared?

Comment: Can you update the code here